# Solve for vertices of a parallelogram given angle and side lengths

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve for the vertices of a parallelogram, given an angle $\theta$ (constant) and variable side lengths `w` and `h`. Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

So, we know the height `H` of the parallelogram to be $w \cdot sin \theta$ and I believe the diagonal `p` is $\sqrt{ w^2 + h^2 - ({2 \cdot w \cdot h \cdot cos(180 - \theta) })}$. With that we can make a right triangle and solve for this new base `c`, which is `w` plus some "jut-out" length.

From there, I pick vertices like:

$v_1$: (0, 0)

$v_2$: (w, 0)

$v_3$: (c, H)

$v_4$: (c - w, H)

However, this isn't working as expected. Changing the width `w` seems to alter the angle of the parallelogram. So I think I've made a mistake somewhere along the way.

### Solution

Thanks guys, the `H` calculation should be $h \cdot sin \theta$. And `c` can be simplified to $w + h \cdot cos \theta$.

Comment: Check possible typo.  $H=h\cdot\sin\theta$ instead of $w\sin\theta$

Comment: Try, $H=h\sin \theta, c=w+h\cos \theta$

Comment: The error is with "$H=\omega \sin \theta$. Instead it should be, $H=h \sin \theta$